# Правильным ли будет написание через тире?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Правильным ли будет написание через тире: "Революция — завтра" (в значении "революция будет завтра")?
Каким правилом это регулируется? Может ли быть "завтра" сказуемым?
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3):

***Революция — завтра.***

Это двусоставное предложение **эллиптического вида** "подлежащее — сказуемое". В таких предложениях сказуемое отсутствует, но подразумевается (будет, наступит и т.д.).

**Тире** ставится, так как обозначает паузу, в противном случае сложно понять структуру предложения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым):  Олимпийский огонь — на нашей земле!